# TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable in nested list

Tags: python

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable.
```

In my code I used a nested list comprehension, the score is float values.

**Question:** Given the names and grades for each student in a Physics class of N students, store them in a nested list and print the name(s) of any student(s) having the second lowest grade.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for _ in range(int(input())):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())
l=[[x,y] for x in name for y in score if (max(score)-y) > 0]
max=l[0]
for mark in l:
    if mark[1]>max[1]:
        max=mark
m=[x[0] for x in l  if (max-x[1])==0]
print(m.sort())
```

Comment: `score` is a number, not an iterable. So `for y in <float>` is not a valid statement

Comment: why don't we use in nested list compreh

Comment: Given the names and grades for each student in a Physics class of N students, store them in a nested list and print the name(s) of any student(s) having the second lowest grade.--Question

Comment: You need to have a list before your first loop then append [name, score] for each iteration. Then sort it accordingly

Comment: Can you explain breifly.@jab

Answer (score 1):

So, as I said in my comment, but more detailed. You need to preserve the student info in a list, then sort the grades to find the second lowest, then loop over them again to print those that are the second lowest grades.

I also **highly** suggest not using `max` as a variable name as it replaces the builtin.

```
students = []
for i in range(1, int(input("How many students? "))+1):
    name = input(f"What is student {i}'s name? ")
    score = float(input(f"What is student {i}'s grade? "))
    students.append([name, score])

second_lowest_grade = sorted({s[1] for s in students})[1]

for student in students:
    if student[1] == second_lowest_grade:
        print(*student, sep=': ')
```

Comment: if there is any duplicants  in the list. Is it works

Comment: Yes, try and see

Answer (score 0):

I enhanced the first comment a little bit:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

students = []
for i in range(1, int(input("How many students? "))+1):
    name = input(f"What is student {i}'s name? ")
    score = float(input(f"What is student {i}'s grade? "))
    students.append([name, score])

student_with_second_lowest_grade = sorted(students, key=lambda t:t[1])[1]
print("Student {0} has the second lowest grade={1}!".format(*student_with_second_lowest_grade))
```

So you can execute this way:

```
# python3 test.py 
How many students? 4
What is student 1's name? John
What is student 1's grade? 10
What is student 2's name? Mary
What is student 2's grade? 9
What is student 3's name? Ken
What is student 3's grade? 8
What is student 4's name? Peter
What is student 4's grade? 7
Student Ken has the second lowest grade=8.0!
```

FYI

Comment: If there is duplicates in the list is to work. Example score=[2,7,7,6,]